# Emacs create cursor

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to create an additional "dummy" cursor in Emacs (preferably multiple)? Ideally I'd like to be able to set its color separately from the original cursor and set its position. Then I'd have the regular cursor that behaves normally, and I'd have multiple extra cursors whose position has to be set by some other means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear on just what your "dummy cursor" would do other than alter the color of the text at its position.  If that's all you want, you could do that with [overlays](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html) or [text properties](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html).  If I'm understanding you properly, you'd probably want to use an overlay, because your "cursor" shouldn't be copied along with the text it's currently sitting on (e.g. if you kill and yank text).

Comment: I think he may actually want bookmarks, but I am not aware of any way to give them color on the buffer.

Comment: @cjm You have a good point. The blinking would just include some simple logic.